# Unity iOS performance issues (low frame rate)

Tags: c#, ios, performance, unity-game-engine

Currently, I have a relatively simple 2D game which should not be too taxing on a cpu. It runs fine on my computer however when I build it to my iPhone or iPad the game starts to be quite jittery and has a poor frame rate. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could improve the performance (I already use object pooling et cetera I think it has something to do with my draw calls / graphics)
EDIT: turns out the renderer is using most of my cpu

Comment: You don't need the Pro version to use the profiler.

Comment: To enable profiler, go to build settings and choose development build, autoconnect profiler, and then go to window and profiler after running the game on the device. Choose the iPhone from the drop down at the top center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is as you say too many draw calls then one simply way to reduce those is to pack your sprites using the [Sprite Packer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html). This places all your sprites tightly which reduces the amount of draw calls, if they don't all fit nicely or there's too many of them then they will be split into subpages. If you'd like to see how to use the Unity texture packer in simple steps I would direct you to this [blog post](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/learn-draw-call-reduction-and-make-your-games-run-superfast) that talks about it in more depth. Here's a simple step by step guide that I based off of the blog post linked.

**Step 1** Select all those sprites that you want to pack in together

**Step 2** Give a Packing Tag as shown in the picture below:

[image]

**Step 3** Open Sprite Packer window and perform packing

[image]

**Step 4** Click the Pack button as seen above

There are also third party tools like [Texture Packer](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) that can do this, and they have more complex algorithms which gives them the edge over Unity's built in verison.

It's also possible there are issues with your games performance not relating directly to draw calls, I would recommend taking a look at the official [Unity guide for mobile optimisation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimizationPracticalGuide.html).

Comment: could it also maybe have something to do with my texture's compression settings not being overrides for iOS?

Comment: It could, that would all depend on the base resolution of your textures. If they're excessively large then you will want to override them for IOS so that they're as low quality as possible without it impacting the aesthetic.

Here's a page about all the different override settings you can have and what one to choose for what texture:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterIos.html